# Dijkstra’s graph returns infinite cost in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, dijkstra, network-analysis

I borrowed some code from the [Network analysis library](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html), modified as appropriate. **The goal** is a program that measures the distance between a location and a train station.

Eventually, this will loop through a series of addresses and stations, but I am testing it on a single pair for now.

**The problem** is, the cost returns infinite instead of a number.

This is the first time actually using any of this code, so I am not sure where to go from here.

The addresses come from an MMQGIS geocoded file, the stations come from a premade file.

```
 graphLayer = 
 QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('tl_2016_17031_addrfeat')[0]
 director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(graphLayer, -1, '', '', '', 3)
 properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
 director.addProperter(properter)
 builder = QgsGraphBuilder(graphLayer.crs())

 stations =QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('CTA_Stations')[0]
 addresses = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('output.shp')[0]

 stationID = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(1)
 addressID = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(1)

 stationStation = next(stations.getFeatures(stationID))
 pStart = QgsPoint(stationStation.attribute('POINT_X'), 
 stationStation.attribute('POINT_Y'))
 addressAddress = next(addresses.getFeatures(addressID))
 pStop = QgsPoint(addressAddress.attribute('Longitude'), 
 addressAddress.attribute('Latitude'))

 #make list of points for all points of interest
 tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, [pStart, pStop])
 graph = builder.graph()

 tStart = tiedPoints[0]
 tStop = tiedPoints[1]

 idStart = graph.findVertex(tStart)
 idStop = graph.findVertex(tStop)

 (tree, cost) = QgsGraphAnalyzer.dijkstra(graph, idStart, 0)
 print cost[graph.findVertex(pStop)]
```

This is where it shows infinite.  When I get the code working, I will use the cost for further work.

Comment: An infinite cost returned from a dijkstra would normally indicate it can't find a valid path - so either the geocodes are off (middle of the sea or too far from a road?) or there's a problem with the road network graph data meaning one part of it isn't connected to another.

Comment: Looks like the station layer doesn't exactly match the streets.  Using to test points on the address layer, it works fine.  (The address layer was geocoded using this street layer, the stations layer was geocoded elsewhere.)  I'll either need to regeocode the station using this street layer, or find a way (if it exists) to link the station layer to the graph.